# Database insert causes docker container to crash?

Tags: mysql, docker, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2. When I make a request that involves making an INSERT query into the database, the request hangs with no response or error thrown, and running `docker ps` takes a while and returns this error:

`Error response from daemon: The requested address is not valid in its context.`

I'd have to restart docker then to get it to work again.

I can make `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, AND `DELETE` queries with no problem.

Now, while debugging, I created a new database and tried to make the same request there, with an `INSERT` query, same code, same hostname, just a different database name used, and the `INSERT` worked.

Has anyone run into this kind of problem before? Any hints? Both databases use `MyISAM` engine.

I'm not sure what other information to include here, please let me know.

UPDATE: This doesn't happen if I perform a `DELETE` query first before executing the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reference for others who will encounter this in the future, the cause for me was referencing a column name with a trailing whitespace (which it should not have), and trying to insert a `NULL` value into a `NOT NULL` field.